# Overloading operator[] keeps throwing a runtime error

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

Alright, so I'm trying to create a Matrix class, and I really, really, want to be able to call elements by using brackets. In the style of mMatrix[x][y].

So I have a `vector<vector<T>>` member, and when overloading the [] operator, I return a reference to a `vector<T>` object.

```
template<class T>
class Matrix
{
private:
    uint32_t DimensionHorizontal;
    uint32_t DimensionVertical;

    std::vector<std::vector<T>> matrix;

public:
    Matrix()
    {
        DimensionHorizontal = 10;
        DimensionVertical = 10;
    }

    std::vector<T>& operator[] (int index)
    {
        return matrix.[index];

    }

    Matrix(int x, int y)
    {
        DimensionHorizontal = x;
        DimensionVertical = y;
    }
};
```

This seems to be working because when I create a Matrix object, and try to add an element by doing Matrix[a][n] (using integers in this case), it compiles without issues. I later try to print out the value stored there with cout.

During runtime, I get the following error

Expression: vector subscript out of range on Line 1455 of the vector. 
On line 1455:

```
_NODISCARD size_type capacity() const noexcept { // return current length of allocated storage
        auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
        return static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Myend - _My_data._Myfirst);
    }

    _NODISCARD _Ty& operator[](const size_type _Pos) noexcept { // strengthened
        auto& _My_data = _Mypair._Myval2;
#if _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0
        _STL_VERIFY(
            _Pos < static_cast<size_type>(_My_data._Mylast - _My_data._Myfirst), "vector subscript out of range");
#endif // _CONTAINER_DEBUG_LEVEL > 0

        return _My_data._Myfirst[_Pos];
    }
```

I am sort of confused about why this is happening. I know I'm trying to access something out of bounds, or doing something otherwise illegal, but Matrix[] should return a vector, and I should be able to use [] again to access the element T (in this case int), any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

This is how I use the class

```
int main()
{
    Matrix<int> a(10, 10);
    a[0][0] = 10;
    std::cout << a[0][0];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try returning  `matrix.at(index);` as very clearly your index is larger than your vector

Comment: This throws an Exception Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCC2A69129 in exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x000000633CD9F250. occurred. Catching the exception and priting it out says "Invalid Vector<T> subscript

Comment: The code never resizes `matrix` to match the dimensions.

Comment: Doesn't vector automatically handle that? Or only when I use push_back()?

Comment: @barieune Do you expect that setting `DimensionHorizontal` and `DimensionHorizontal` member variables should result in resizing of `matrix`? These are totally independent objects. How could they "know" about each other?

Comment: ***Doesn't vector automatically handle that?*** No, it does not resize when you access an out of bounds index..

Comment: Frankly, I wasn't expecting that I'd have to resize the vectors, because I though that they dynamically allocate space when one tries to add new elements. As in, I can declare a vector<int> and keep adding as many integers as I want with push_back. It didn't dawn on me that using the [] operator would be any different. In case it wasn't painfully obvious by now, I'm pretty new to this ^^ Anyway, I learned something new, so thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to resize the matrix in your constructor to match the size passed as arguments.

```
 Matrix(int x, int y) : matrix(x)
 {
    for( auto& sub : matrix ) {
       sub.resize(y);
    }
    DimensionHorizontal = x;
    DimensionVertical = y;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, however that doesn't seem to solve it. Same error as before :/

Comment: `for (sub : matrix)` is totally wrong, missing `auto` and even with that, it will resize a copy of inner vector. Use `for (auto & sub : matrix) sub.resize(y);` instead.

Comment: Holy crap that worked, I caught the missing auto earlier, but it didn't dawn on me that it had to be a reference. Thanks @Daniel says reinstate Monica I've been at this for days

Comment: sorry was in a bit of a rush, normally I compile the code first ...